# trying to work which hour of the day is busiest for a small business using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Using dummy data relating to a small boutique I'm trying to work out which hour of the day is busiest using data collected over a period of 3 months. I'm using SQL to build my query and I have no idea where to start, I've already figured out the busiest day but I'm struggling with the use of time.  Here is a sample of my data, again I'm just struggling in how exactly to build my query:

```
SALE_ID PRODUCT_NAME    PRICE_RANGE PRODUCT_COST    DATEOF  DAY_OF_WEEK TIME
1   DRESS   HIGH    69  2/18/2017   3   13:43
2   TRAINERS    MEDIUM  48  1/1/2017    3   9:21
5   TROUSERS    HIGH    70  3/2/2017    4   9:20
6   TROUSERS    MEDIUM  30  3/30/2017   4   17:00
7   SHORTS  LOW 23  3/27/2017   4   16:25
8   TROUSERS    MEDIUM  53  3/28/2017   4   9:00
10  TROUSERS    MEDIUM  32  3/3/2017    4   9:40
11  SHIRT   HIGH    88  3/12/2017   4   9:50
9   TRAINERS    MEDIUM  36  3/31/2017   4   9:30
12  TRAINERS    HIGH    100 1/20/2017   4   9:10
13  DRESS   MEDIUM  48  2/26/2017   4   9:40
14  SHOES   MEDIUM  35  1/31/2017   4   10:41
16  TROUSERS    MEDIUM  30  2/27/2017   4   10:19
17  TROUSERS    LOW 21  3/10/2017   4   9:15
18  DRESS   HIGH    92  1/23/2017   4   10:24
19  SHIRT   HIGH    84  3/6/2017    4   9:05
20  TRAINERS    LOW 27  1/21/2017   4   10:26
21  TROUSERS    HIGH    88  2/27/2017   4   10:55
23  HAT MEDIUM  34  1/25/2017   4   12:19
25  SHOES   LOW 22  1/6/2017    4   12:30
26  BELT    HIGH    86  2/25/2017   4   12:45
27  DRESS   HIGH    84  3/26/2017   4   9:50
28  JACKET  HIGH    99  2/20/2017   4   12:45
29  SHIRT   MEDIUM  48  2/21/2017   4   13:00
31  TRAINERS    HIGH    92  2/3/2017    4   12:25
32  BELT    MEDIUM  84  3/27/2017   4   10:10
33  TRAINERS    LOW 27  2/12/2017   3   13:29
34  SHORTS  HIGH    88  1/18/2017   4   16:06
35  HAT HIGH    87  2/9/2017    4   14:26
```

Answer (score 0):

If `DATEOF`   is a `DATE` column and has time component, you could group by the hour component.

```
select hour_of_day , tph
FROM
(
select TO_CHAR(dateof,'HH24') hour_of_day,count(*) tph
FROM
salestable
GROUP  BY TO_CHAR(dateof,'HH24')
ORDER BY tph desc
) where ROWNUM = 1 ;
```

If you don't have a time component and need to use `time` column, then you could  utilize `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` to extract the hour from `time`.

```
select hour_of_day , tph
FROM
(
select SUBSTR(time,1,INSTR(time,':')-1) hour_of_day,count(*) tph
FROM salestable GROUP  BY SUBSTR(time,1,INSTR(time,':')-1)
ORDER BY tph desc
) where ROWNUM = 1 ;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1dcdf0/1)